# In Visual Studio 2010, can you tell me which files store build settings?

Tags: visual-studio

I've set up Visual Studio 2010 with two build configurations, one builds to *.dll, the other to *64.dll. I need to know which in which file is this stored so I can submit it, but I don't want submit to many irrelevant files?

Also, how would I set Visual Studio to compile both at the same time?
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configurations are saved in the `.vcproj` files.

For multiple builds, go to the `Build` menu, select `Batch Build` and check all configurations you want built.